# Adding a "passive" plot in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to add a plot to a `pgfplots` figure, but such that it doesn't change the automatically computed limits. for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}%[ymin=-6,ymax=6]
\addplot+ {x};
\addplot+ {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As written, the secont plot alters the limits. I could manually specify the limits (by removing the comment), but that's precisely what I want to avoid. Is there an option for this? I've found the `forget plot` option, but that's not quite what I need.

Comment: I see a `pgfplotsinterruptdatabb` environment in the `pgfplots` documentation, isn't that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a single plot, you can use the option `update limits=false`.

For several plots, you can wrap them in the environment `pgfplotsinterruptdatabb`.

In both cases, the result is the same: the given plots do not contribute to the computation of the bounding box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}%[ymin=-6,ymax=6]
    \addplot+ {x};
    \addplot+ {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}%[ymin=-6,ymax=6]
    \addplot+ {x};
    \addplot+[update limits=false] {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}%[ymin=-6,ymax=6]
    \addplot+ {x};
    \begin{pgfplotsinterruptdatabb}
      \addplot+ {x^2};
    \end{pgfplotsinterruptdatabb}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was looking for, but with such a big manual it's sometimes difficult to find things (and I was expecting to see some example). Now I have to solve a problem with dimensions too large (not in this test, but in my real case)